# My Bootstrap Hamburger Menu Won't Show Links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

so I've been looking at my code for quite a while right now and I can't figure out why my bootstrap hamburger menu won't show the links when you click on it. I've checked the data-target and the class/id name to make sure they matched, but it still doesn't show.

```
    <header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
        <img id="brand-image" alt="Web Logo" src="images/logo.png"> 
      </a>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <a href="coal.html">COAL</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="electric.html">ELECTRIC</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="wind.html">WIND</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="credits.html">CREDITS</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using? This code works for me.

Comment: Never mind found it. For people with similar problems, I just added these two pieces of code within the body and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Have you included bootstrap.min.js and jQuery.js? The button needs both javascript libraries to work.

Comment: <script> src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script> src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: @nealred Thanks, yeah I was searching around and I needed to include bootstrap.min.js and jQuery.js. I just overlooked it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You maybe forgot to import the Bootstrap Javascript file or the jQuery file? It can't work without them.

Just add this in the end of your body tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps